# How to fix lags/clipping on mobile with a dynamic background-position?

Tags: angularjs, css, mobile, css-animations

I'm working on a small app where the user move the background with his finger on the screen.

The `background-position` is defined by the position of the finger.

I'm using angular, so I have this kind of tags:

```
<div class="main-container" ng-touchmove="onTouchmove($event)">
    <div class="image" ng-style="{ 'background-position': bgPosition }"></div>
</div>
```

And in my controller:

```
$scope.onTouchmove = function (e) {
    $scope.bgPosition = e.touches[0].pageX + 'px ' + e.touches[0].pageY + 'px';
};
```

However, I have significant lags on mobile and the background is "clipping". 
The issue seems to be common and people often suggest to use `transform` over `background-position`.

But how could I use `transform` if the position is based on the movements of the user? Globally, how can I avoid these lags?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want this:

```
$scope.bgPosition = e.touches[0].pageX + 'px ' + e.touches[0].pageY + 'px';
```

to be something like

```
$scope.transform = 'translate(' + e.touches[0].pageX + 'px, ' + e.touches[0].pageY + 'px)';
```

(and change `{ 'background-position': bgPosition }` to `{ 'transform': transform}` or similar.)

You will also may need to add another html element between `.main-container` and `.image` if you don't want to use main-container to crop the image. Something like

```
.crop-image {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

or

```
.crop-image {
    clip: rect(/* dimensions offset from top and left. */)
}
```

(overflow might work for your needs, but if not check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).